# Jquery Css Get old position from div?

Tags: jquery, css, position

I asked me if there is anyway to get an old position from a div in my case the `.tile` moves to the left corner when its been clicked. when i click the close button it should go back to the OLD position.

Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2Zx3m/4/)

```
$(".tile").on("click", function (e) {
     var pos = $(this).position();

    e.stopPropagation();
    if(!$(this).hasClass('open') ) {
        $(this).animate({
            "top": pos.top - pos.top,
            "left":pos.left - pos.left,
            "width": "100%",
            "height": "100%"
        }, 1000).addClass('open');
    }
});



$(".close").on("click", function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).parent().stop().animate({
        // here i need the old position
        "width": "100px",
        "height": "50px"
    }, 1000).removeClass('open');
});
```

CSS

```
.tile {
    position: absolute;
    background-color:#0090db;

}
#tp1{
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;       
}

.close {
    display: none;
    background-color:#C85051;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 5px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 25px;
    text-align: center;
}

.open .close {
    display: block;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="tile" id="tp1">
    <img class="bus" src="http://s14.directupload.net/images/131130/4gzq9oaz.png" />
    <div class="close">x</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything to solve it yet?

Comment: Please could you add all relevant code to the question itself. Stackoverlow cannot rely on jsFiddle always being available. Think of future readers of this question and how a self-contained question and answer would help them.

Comment: @James
Yes i tried some thinks new variable and other stuff im new to jquery sry.

Comment: @andyb Oh sry did not think of that i am new here but thanks for the info :)

Comment: I updated the code i hope its ok now.

Comment: Refer to my answer for a much cleaner way to do this. Best of luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're positioning your elements with `position:absolute` one option is create two `var` that keeps the first value position:

```
var posL , posT;
```

And then assign the values on the `click` function like this:

```
 var posL = $(this).css('left'),
     posT = $(this).css('top');
```

Review this demo **http://jsfiddle.net/2Zx3m/10/**

**Edit**

To take in care with the `global var` as point the user gaynorvader you can call all your code into an anonymus function like this:

```
(function(){ 
    /* code */ 
}())
```

About the reason for taking care of `global var` you can see more [here](http://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/scope/) and [here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/the-10-javascript-mistakes-youre-making/)

Also you can se more about the [Immediately-Invoked Function](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/)

Comment: I see how you did. I am new to jquery i doid not know how to make global variables . Thanks for your help

Comment: @gaynorvader Can you explain why?

Comment: It's just a neatness thing. It's good practice to not use them. http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/the-10-javascript-mistakes-youre-making/
A small piece of code like this it's probably fine though.

Comment: @gaynorvader I see thanks for share ... in this case i guess doesn't matter but the OP can avoid that making an anonymus function. Let me edit the post.

Answer (score 0):

Get the old position... no. Remember the old position... of course. Just save current position before moving.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the position of the element using jQuery's data.

More information here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/

```
$(".tile").on("click", function (e) { //opens the login
     var pos = $(this).position();

    e.stopPropagation();
    if(!$(this).hasClass('open') ) {
        $(this).animate({
            "top": pos.top - pos.top,
            "left":pos.left - pos.left,
            "width": "100%",
            "height": "100%"
        }, 1000).addClass('open');
        $(this).data('pos', pos); // Save the position here
    }
});

$(".close").on("click", function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    var elem = $(this).parent();
    var pos = elem.data('pos'); // Retrieve the position
    elem.stop().animate({
        "top": pos.top,
        "left": pos.left,
        "width": "100px",
        "height": "50px"
    }, 1000).removeClass('open');
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2Zx3m/11/)

Answer (score 0):

Use `margin-left`. Set it negatively to the position of the element then set it back to 0 when going back: http://jsfiddle.net/2Zx3m/12/

```
$(this).animate({
            "top": pos.top - pos.top,
            //"left":pos.left - pos.left,
            "margin-left": - pos.left,
            "width": "100%",
            "height": "100%"
        }, 1000).addClass('open');
```

And back:

```
 $(this).parent().stop().animate({
        // here i need the old position
        "margin-left": 0, 
        "width": "100px",
        "height": "50px"
    }, 1000).removeClass('open');
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would go about it with minimal code and frustration.

I am using jQuery `toggleClass` to rely mostly on CSS for its position.

The HTML:

```
<div class="car left">
   <img src="http://s14.directupload.net/images/131130/4gzq9oaz.png" alt="bus" class="minBus" />
   <span class="close">X</span>
</div>

<div class="car right">
   <img src="http://s14.directupload.net/images/131130/4gzq9oaz.png" alt="bus" class="minBus" />
   <span class="close">X</span>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
html, body {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}

.car {
   background: lightBlue;
   width: 160px;
   height: 70px;
   float: left;
   position: absolute;
   transition: all 1s ease;
   -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
   -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
   -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
   -o-transition: all 1s ease;
}

.car.active {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   left: 0;
   z-index: 10;
}

.right {
   left: 400px;
}

.minBus {
   width: 140px;
   height: 56px;
   transition: all 1s ease;
   -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
   -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
   -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
   -o-transition: all 1s ease;
}

.minBus.active {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}

.close {
   display: none;
   position: absolute;
   right: 0;
   top: 0;
   background: brown;
   width: 40px;
   height: 40px;
   text-align: center;
   line-height: 40px;
}

.close.active {
   display: block;
}
```

The tiny bit of jQuery:

```
function toggle() {
   $('.car').on('click', function() {
       $(this).toggleClass('active').find('.minBus, .close').toggleClass('active');
   });
}

toggle();
```

This is using the styles to toggle between, so there is no calculation needed.

Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_JM/38QZ7/2/).

The great thing about this is that jQuery isn't pumping in a bunch of `inline-styles`. Instead of the `.animate` we are switching classes which hold all of the styles inside of them.

Comment: You do lose the animation with this approach though :(

Comment: @gaynorvader The only way it doesn't animate is if you are using an out of date browser like IE9 and below. For most current browsers you will be fine.

Comment: But with this method i lose the animation of the bus fading away and the bus and the tile are not moveing at the same time. But thanks for your work.